# How to display a property of an object in jsp

Tags: jsp, spring-mvc

I have stores several object in a list and want to display it in jsp. So my current code is:

controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value="browse", method=RequestMethod.GET)
public String showBrowsePage(final RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes) {
    List<ItemImages> imgList = imgManager.displayAllImgs();
    redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute( "imgList", imgList );
    return "general/browse";
}
```

and my jsp:

```
<c:forEach items="${imgList}" var="image">
        <li class="item_showcase">
            <div class="item_image">
                <a href="item" title="${image.description}">
                    <img src=<c:url value="${image.itemImgPath}"  /> />
                </a>
            </div>
        </li>       
</c:forEach>
```

The problem I have is it doesnt display images as well as the description of the image. If I change the value of , it would work fine.

Comment: I don't know what you are asking and I don't know what the problem is. Please clarify what you expect to happen and what actually happens.

Comment: what you mean by `_If I change the value of , it would work fine._`??

Comment: Sorry for the misinterpretation. The itemImgPath contents the relative path to image resource. If I change it to <img src="resources/image/1.png" />, it would display an image. So I want to store all the path and description into the ItemImages and display it in the jsp dynamically.

Comment: How about when using plain EL? `<img src="${image.itemImgPath}"/>`